# Output parameter not set if stored procedure fails inside a TRY / CATCH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameter, error-handling

In SQL Server 2008 (but also in 2014). Let's consider a procedure that has an output parameter. This procedure may produce an error (and will in the following example). I note that the behaviour of the output parameter is not the same if we call the procedure within a `TRY` / `CATCH` block.

Example:

```
create procedure test_output @result varchar(10) output
as
begin
    set @result = 'hello'
    raiserror('This is an error', 16,1)
    set @result = 'error'
end
```

If we launch the procedure the simple way:

```
declare @res1 varchar(10)
exec test_output @result = @res1 out
print 'Result is: '+ isnull(@res1, 'empty')
```

we get (and I'm fine with it):

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test_output, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 12]
>   This is an error
>   Result is: error

If the procedure is now in a try/catch block:

```
declare @res2 varchar(10)
declare @error_message varchar(max)
begin try
    exec test_output @result = @res2 out
end try
begin catch
    set @error_message = error_message()
    raiserror(@error_message, 16,1)
    print 'Result is: '+ isnull(@res2, 'empty')
end catch
```

we get (and I'm upset):

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
>   This is an error
>   Result is: empty

The error message is OK, but the output parameter is now **NULL**. If, in a `TRY...CATCH` context, the execution is halted immediately after the `RAISERROR`, I would have expected the output value to be set to **hello**.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're off to a good start with that test setup, but it is missing something that is causing you to misinterpret what is actually happening. If you put in `PRINT` statements at the beginning, middle, and end of the stored procedure then the additional output will make it clearer as to what is going on here. For example:

```
USE [tempdb];
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE test_output
(
  @Result VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @Result = 'hello';

    PRINT 1;
    RAISERROR('This is an error', 16, 1);

    PRINT 2;
    SET @Result = 'error';

    PRINT 3;
END;
GO
```

The output from your first test query is:

```
1
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test_output, Line xxxx [Batch Start Line yyyyy]
This is an error
2
3
Result is: error
```

And that is probably what you were expecting anyway. But, the output from the second test query is:

```
1
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line xxxxx
This is an error
Result is: empty
```

That is quite a bit different. We can now see that within the `TRY...CATCH` construct, execution is halted *immediately* upon the `RAISERROR` being called (i.e. it becomes a batch-aborting event). On the other hand, `RAISERROR` does not immediately halt execution when not called within a `TRY...CATCH` construct.

However, as you pointed out in your update to the question, this does not explain why the `OUTPUT` parameter is not then set to `hello`. That is due to the intention of normal stored procedure behavior to *not* reflect partial execution (due to a batch-aborting error). This is discussed in the following blog post:

[TSQL Basics II – Parameter Passing Semantics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/06/09/tsql-basics-ii-parameter-passing-semantics)

Meaning: even though the stored procedure did execute the step setting the variable to `hello`, the `RAISERROR` is now a batch-aborting error when called within a `TRY...CATCH` construct, and stored procedures do not reflect any changes to parameters when they are aborted.

This behavior is also at the heart of the following explanation:

[Why must TVPs be READONLY, and why can't parameters of other types be READONLY](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120756/why-must-tvps-be-readonly-and-why-cant-parameters-of-other-types-be-readonly/120775#120775)